# How can I update one element from a flask app on a button click?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, jinja2

In my app.py I have a list of strings, eg:

```
list = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
```

I would like to be able to be shown a string at random and display it on a page after clicking a 'refresh' button, but each item should only be shown once. ie. once the items have all been shown in random order I can show a message 'finished'.

I have looked into refreshing the page (shown below) but this means the items can appear one after the other and I can always keep refreshing. This is my work-in-progress code at the moment, but I feel as if it's not close to what I want.

```
items_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/items", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def items():        
    item = random.choice(items_list)

    if request.method == "POST":
        return render_template("scales.html", item=item)

    else:
        return render_template("scales.html")
```

items.html:

```
<div>
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
    <form action="/items" method="post">
        <button onClick="window.location.reload();" type="button">Refresh</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Perhaps I could do this with AJAX? But would I need a database?
Or something along the lines of `app.jinja_env.globals.update()`
At a bit of a loss and any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Ajax or Websockets to display your result. However it also works the "normal" way you have implemented it.

You should declare your button as a submit button to trigger the `POST` event. This will route you to the `items()` endpoint.

```
<form action="/items" method="post">
    <button type="submit" type="button">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

To make sure each item will get shown only once you need to remove it from your list.

```
@app.route("/items", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def items():        
    item = random.choice(items_list)
    items_list.remove(item)
```

But then you should also think about what to do if no item is left anymore.

Comment: Thanks this helped me getting towards what I needed! I ended up having an extra route for dealing with the data that just redirects when it’s done (the data was a bit more complicated than my example). Thanks again!